# URL for the pdf file using PHP

Tags: php, url

I am trying to generate an URL for my pdf file stored on my localhost. I dynamically retrieve the pdf name and append it to the path of the folder where the pdf is stored and store the url in a variable which I wanted to use later.

My code follows like this:

```
    $pdf = 'data.pdf';
    $path = "H:\xampp\htdocs\testing\ ";
    $path_replaced = str_replace(" ", "", $path);
    $url = $path_replaced . $pdf;
    echo $url;
```

but unfortunately instead of getting "H:\xampp\htdocs\testing\data.pdf", I am getting this as output "H: mpp\htdocs esting\0023.pdf "

Any reason why this is happening!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
 $path = 'H:\xampp\htdocs\testing\ ';
```

If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters like  `\t`

look on http://li.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 1):

`\t` is a tab-character and thus you need to escape the string. Or use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes:

```
$path = 'H:\xampp\htdocs\testing\ ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *single quotes* (') to store your string.

You are using back-slashes "\" which when used within double quotes are recognised as special characters when combined with letters (i.e. "\n" = *new line*, or "\t" = *tab*).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have \t in your path, which funny enough equals to a tab. You should. When defining something like this, you should always use single-quotes, like this:

```
$path = 'H:\xampp\htdocs\testing\ ';
```